# Is it possible to reverse svds

Tags: matlab, svd

Is it possible to reverse the following in matlab:

```
[U,S,V]=svds(fulldata,columns);
```

Comment: Is this some sort of trick question?

Comment: Definition of SVD is X = U*S*V' (as noted by Sjlver below). Reversing is the easy part. Actually decomposing the matrix via SVD is far more challenging.

Comment: what exactly are you asking for? Can one, from a small number of singular values, reconstruct `fulldata` no... you only get an approximation

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Quoting [MathWorks](http://www.mathworks.ch/ch/help/matlab/ref/svd.html):

[U,S,V] = svd(X) produces a diagonal matrix S of the same dimension as X, with nonnegative diagonal elements in decreasing order, and unitary matrices U and V so that X = U*S*V'.

In the case of svds, one will lose some information unless `columns` is equal to the size of the square matrix `fulldata`. In this case, I believe the original matrix cannot be reconstructed uniquely.

Comment: Note that the OP asks for `svds`, not `svd`.

Comment: @Rasman yes, but he had `svds` from the first version of the question.